# Docker compose orphan containers when overriding services

Tags: docker, docker-compose, buildbot

I want to have two docker-compose files, where one overrides another.
*(The motivation comes from [Docker Compose Docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#/multiple-compose-files))*
The use case comes from the buildbot environment. The first docker-compose file should define a simple service. This is a service that is going to be tested. Let's take

```
version: '2'
services:
  service-node:
    build:
      context: ./res
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: my/server
    env_file: .env
```

The second docker-compose file (let's name it *docker-compose.test.yml*) overrides the service-node to add a buildbot worker feature, and creates the second container, i.e. buildbot master node, that is going to control testing machinery. Let's take

```
version: '2'
services:
  service-node:
    build:
      context: ./res
      dockerfile: buildbot.worker.Dockerfile
    image: my/buildbot-worker
    container_name: bb-worker
    env_file: ./res/buildbot.worker.env
    environment:
      - BB_RES_DIR=/var/lib/buildbot
    networks:
      testlab:
        aliases:
          - bb-worker
    volumes:
      - ./vol/bldbot/worker:/home/bldbotworker
    depends_on:
      - bb-master

  bb-master:
    build:
      context: ./res
      dockerfile: buildbot.master.Dockerfile
    image: my/buildbot-master
    container_name: bb-master
    env_file: ./res/buildbot.master.env
    environment:
      - BB_RES_DIR=/var/lib/buildbot
    networks:
      - testlab
    expose:
      - "9989"
    volumes:
      - ./vol/bldbot/master:/var/lib/buildbot

networks:
  testlab:
    driver: bridge
```

Generally this configuration works, i.e. the command

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.test.yml up -d
```

builds both images and runs both containers, but there is one shortcoming, i.e. the command

```
docker-compose ps
```

shows only one service, bb-worker. At the same time

```
docker ps
```

shows both.
Furthermore, the command

```
docker-compose down
```

stops only one service, and outputs the message/warning `Found orphan containers`. Of course, the message refers to bb-master.

How can I override the basic docker-compose.yml file to be able to add additional non-orphan service?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to run all `docker-compose` commands with the flags, e.g.:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.test.yml down
```

Alternatively, you can make this the default by writing the following to a `.env` file in the same folder:

```
COMPOSE_FILE=docker-compose.yml:docker-compose.test.yml
```

**NOTE:**

In windows you need tu use ";" as the separator (@louisvno)

Comment: Brilliant. Sometimes the most obvious solutions are so close that one cannot see them. Thank you. It works like charm.

Comment: So I´ve been literally pulling my hair until I saw this answer. Great

Comment: just a tip for the windows ppl, the separator is ; instead of :